# Nested Group by with count and average

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Agreements': ["Rome", "NewYork", "Paris", "Tokyo"], 'Year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2013], 
     'Provision1': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'Provision2': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'Provision3': [0, 1, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

| Agreements | Year | Provision1 | Provision2 | Provision3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rome | 2012 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| NewYork | 2012 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Paris | 2013 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Tokyo | 2013 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I would like to group by to obtain as output:

| Year | Count Agreements per Year | Count Provisions per Year | Average Provision per Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 2 | 5 | 2.5 |
| 2013 | 2 | 4 | 2 |

I have tried with `df.groupby('Year')['Agreements'].count().reset_index(name='counts')` but I do not know how to expand it to obtain the output I desire. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75303433/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = df.assign(
    Provisions=df.loc[:, "Provision1":"Provision3"].sum(axis=1)
).pivot_table(
    index="Year", aggfunc={"Agreements": "count", "Provisions": ("sum", "mean")}
)
out.columns = [
    f'{b.capitalize().replace("Mean", "Average")} {a} per Year' for a, b in out.columns
]
print(out.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Year | Count Agreements per Year | Average Provisions per Year | Sum Provisions per Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 2 | 2.5 | 5 |
| 2013 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

---

EDIT: To add column with the count of "Agreements with at least one Provision":

```py
out = df.assign(
    Provisions=df.loc[:, "Provision1":"Provision3"].sum(axis=1),
    AggreementsWithAtLeastOneProvision=df.loc[:, "Provision1":"Provision3"].any(axis=1)
).pivot_table(
    index="Year", aggfunc={"Agreements": "count", "AggreementsWithAtLeastOneProvision": "sum", "Provisions": ("sum", "mean")}
)
out.columns = [
    f'{b.capitalize().replace("Mean", "Average")} {a} per Year' for a, b in out.columns
]
print(out.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Year | Sum AggreementsWithAtLeastOneProvision per Year | Count Agreements per Year | Average Provisions per Year | Sum Provisions per Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 2 | 3 | 1.66667 | 5 |
| 2013 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

Input data in this case was:

```
   Agreements  Year  Provision1  Provision2  Provision3
0  Bratislava  2012           0           0           0
1        Rome  2012           1           1           0
2     NewYork  2012           1           1           1
3       Paris  2013           1           0           1
4       Tokyo  2013           1           1           0
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. How would it change if I would like to add a column with the values of "Agreements with at least one Provision" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` and `agg`:

```
out = (df.assign(Average=lambda x: x.filter(like='Provision').sum(axis=1))
         .melt(id_vars=['Year', 'Agreements', 'Average'], var_name='Provision').groupby('Year')
         .agg(**{'Count Agreements per Year': ('Agreements', 'nunique'),
                 'Count Provisions per Year': ('value', 'sum'),
                 'Average Provision per Year': ('Average', 'mean')})
         .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Year  Count Agreements per Year  Count Provisions per Year  Average Provision per Year
0  2012                          2                          5                         2.5
1  2013                          2                          4                         2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.iloc[:,1:].set_index('Year').stack().to_frame()
 .pivot_table(index='Year', values=0, aggfunc=[lambda x: 
     x.count() / 3, 'sum', lambda x: x.sum()/(x.count() / 3)])
 .set_axis(['Count Agreements per Year', 'Count Provisions per Year', 
                  'Average Provision per Year'], axis=1).reset_index())
```

---

Using a `numpy` approach:

```
a = df.iloc[:,1:].values
colnames = ['Year','Count Agreements per Year',
            'Count Provisions per Year', 'Average Provision per Year' ]
pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack(
        [[x[0,0], np.size(x[:,1:])/3, np.sum(x[:,1:]), 
          np.sum(x[:,1:])/(np.size(x[:,1:])/3)] 
         for x in [a[np.where(a[:, 0] == val)] for val in np.unique(a[:, 0])]]), 
    columns=colnames).convert_dtypes()
```

---

Output:

```
   Year  Count Agreements per Year  Count Provisions per Year  \
0  2012                          2                          5   
1  2013                          2                          4   

   Average Provision per Year  
0                         2.5  
1                         2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to approach this, here is a simple one:

First, combine all "Provision" columns into one column:

```
# combining all Provision columns into one column
df['All_Provisions'] = df['Provision1'] + df['Provision2'] + df['Provision3']
```

Second, aggregate the columns using [.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), which takes your columns and desired aggregations as a dictionary. In our case, we want to:

1. count "Agreements" column
2. sum "All_Provisions" column
3. average "All_Provisions" column

We can do it like:

```
# aggregating columns
df = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False).agg({'Agreements':'count', 'All_Provisions':['sum', 'mean']})
```

Finally, rename your columns:

```
# renaming columns
df.columns = ['Year','Count Agreements per Year','Count Provisions per Year','Average Provision per Year']
```

Hope this helps :)